# Lagrangian density transformation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, dirac-matrices, chirality, invariants

In a calculation of a Lagrangian density $$
\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}\left(i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}-m+i \gamma_{5} m^{\prime}\right) \psi.
$$
In order to see if it is invariant or not with the transformation,

$$
\psi(x) \longrightarrow e^{-i \beta \gamma_{5}} \psi(x) \quad \text { e } \quad \bar{\psi}(x) \longrightarrow \bar{\psi}(x) e^{-i \beta \gamma_{5}}
$$

I am in doubt regarding the calculation of the:
$$
i \gamma_{5} m^{\prime}.
$$
I used exponential expansion in $\cos$ and $\sin$, and my colleague did the explicit expansion of $\exp$ in Taylor series giving him that this term is invariant, contrary to what he gave me. I would like to get other people's opinion on this calculation.

Comment: The $\gamma_5$ commute between themselves

Comment: the $\gamma^{5}$ commute with the  e$^{-I\beta\gamma^{5}}$?

Comment: Could you provide your calculation so that we can tell you where the error is?

Comment: $$
\exp \left(-i \beta \gamma^{5}\right) \gamma_{s} \exp \left(-i \beta \gamma^{5}\right)
$$
$$
\left(\cos (\beta)-i \operatorname{sen}(\beta) \gamma^{5}\right) \gamma_{5}\left(\cos \beta_{1}-i \operatorname{sen}\left(\beta\right)\gamma^{5})\right.
$$
$$
\left[\cos (\beta) \gamma_{5}-i \operatorname{sen}(\beta)\right]\left[\cos \beta-i \operatorname{sen}(\beta) \gamma_{5}\right]
$$

Comment: $$
\cos ^{2}(\beta)\gamma_{5}+\operatorname{sen}^{2}(\beta) \gamma_{5} -i \operatorname{sen}(\beta) \cos (\beta) \gamma_{5} \gamma_{5}-i \operatorname{sen}(\beta) \cos (\beta)
$$
$$
\gamma_{s}-2i \sin (\beta) \cos (\beta)
$$$$
\gamma_{s}-2i \sin (2\beta)
$$
this two comments is my method

Comment: Your last line, right above this, has an extra 2 in front of *i*. In addition, crucially, the first line of this last comment has a wrong sign: the + should have been - . So, then you'd have a $\cos (2\beta) \gamma_5$

Comment: Besides the obvious DeMoivre formula, if you just think about the Taylor expansion of $\exp(-i\beta\gamma_5)$ is going to have various powers of the $\gamma_5$. But since all the $\gamma_5$ commute with themselves, and this is trivial, than you can put the initial $\gamma_5$ which is not in the exponential expansion, to the left (or to the right) of the whole expansion, getting back the exponential and the $\gamma_5$ to the left (or right). So basically yes, $\exp(-i\beta\gamma_5)$ and $\gamma_5$ commute.